# Install PDO-driver for Postgresql

Tags: centos, php

When i run

```
PDO::getAvailableDrivers()
```

i can see that the only available driver is sqlite, and i want to use Postgresql. What should i do to accomplish that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yum install php5-pgsql
```

*pdo_pgsql* is included in *php5-pgsql*.

Comment: There is no such package available...

Comment: That's probably because this package doesn't exist in the default repository. [Here](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) you can find instructions about how to add a repository that contains these packages.

Comment: I tried "yum install php54w-pgsql", but then PHP wont work at all (printed in plain text)

Comment: Worked it out. Thought php54w-pgsql was a package with php and pgsql, and not only an update. Installed php54w again and php54w-pgsql on top of that :)

Comment: Using php5-pgsql solved my problem on CentOS 6

Comment: For php 5.6 the correct command is: yum install php56u-pgsql Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to run for php 5.5:

```
yum install php55w-pgsql
```

For php 5.6 command is:

```
yum install php56w-pgsql
```

If you need another php extension, please read this article: [PHP 5.6 on CentOS/RHEL 7.1 and 6.7 via Yum](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install same driver in PHP 7.0

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
yum install php70w-pgsql
```

Comment: Thanks,. After restart server apache. sudo yum install php-pdo_pgsql

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this site](https://varunver.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/centos-7-install-php-and-postgres/), in order to install php-pgsql connector on RHEL/Centos, you need to install php-pgsql package:

## yum install php-pgsql

I've used it and it worked!

Comment: This is the same answer that was suggested 8 years ago in 2012.

Comment: Not exactly the same package, though

Comment: I would estimate more than 3 people have suggested the same solution.  The only thing that is different is your suggested to install whatever is the current version of the module.  The accepted answer is virtually identical to that of this answer for that reason.